# Which of these classifiers are better?

Tags: machine-learning

I'm not sure which classifier is better out of the following two:

`Classifier 1 - Training set = 100%, Test set 70%` and 
`Classifier 2 - Training set = 70%, Test set 75%`

I need to argue that Classifier 1 is better than Classifier 2.

Both have their pro's and con's but I don't have a concrete answer?

Comment: When you ask "better" you need to also add a "for what" - you need to compare against some sort of criteria, which you have not.

Comment: @Oded, modified the question

Comment: @nsc010, you still haven't explained the "for what" that Oded asked. The sentence "I need to argue that C1 is better than C2" leads me to believe that you are not interested in a fair comparison -- why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second is probably better.

The first classifier is clearly suffering from [overfit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting). In other words, instead of learning the underlying principles of your training set, it is learning an exaustive description of your data.

This doesn't mean that the second classifier is great. But, in general, classifier A is better than classifier B if the performance on the test set of A is better than that of B.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the details you have provided, it appears that Classifier 1 is overfitted to the training set in comparison to Classifier 2, and therefore has performed more poorly against the test set. This would suggest that Classifier 2 is 'better' in respects to the test set.

If you wanted to argue the other way, you would probably need to point to some specifics about  Classifier 1 that could make it so - e.g. how was it trained, what algorithms were used.